# Criteria to choose a good Java rules engine for a fraud detection application

Tags: java, business-rules

I have to use a Java rule engine for a fraud detection application, then have to make some comparison between some engines. Could anyone help me to make a list of criteria of choice, or suggest some good BRMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I like [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools). It's fast, it works and it's actively supported. And if you need this level of warm and fuzzy, several large financial institutions are using it for advanced analysis and trading applications (though I can't mention names).

Comment: thank you for reply, I consider to use DROOLS, it seems it's the best solution for my appication , but before doing this, i have to make a comparaion between some products in ordre to convince my internship supervisor of this solution,(please tolerate my broken English)